# Ribbon gets focus when trying to switch language

Tags: wpf, user-interface, ribbon

I am using Microsoft's implementation of the ribbon control in my WPF application. My application supports different languages. The problem is when I try to switch the language (using ALT + SHIFT combination) to enter data in a text box for example, the Ribbon steels focus which is pretty annoying for the user. I use Office and it doesn't have this issue because if you switch languages using that combination, it will regain focus from the ribbon and I want behavior similar to that.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that ribbon has a hotkey bound by default, what i suggest is that you try overriding that key combinations by binding an empty command to it.

```
<Ribbon.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding x:Null}"
                Gesture="ALT+TAB"/>
</Ribbon.InputBindings
```

Comment: I know that Vidas, thank you. but the thing is that i want to keep that functionality for keyboard navigation. i just don't want it to get in the way when the user tries to input into a text box for instance.